# SQL server Management Studio: Search produces "Search invalid " result always

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssms, management-studio-express

Ok so I was looking for an option using which i could locate a particular Table or Proc in Object explorer if i know the name just to avoid the whole scrolling thingy  in the object explorer pane (some thing like a 'ctrl+ [ + S' shortcut of Visual Studio.)

And then i found a link which said there is a search box provided in Object explorer 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/02/26/sql-server-find-anything-in-object-explorer-in-ssms/

I am using Management studio 2014 but i dont see any search Box! as MSDN says in the article
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646011.aspx

Can any one let me know if this search box is missing in 2014 edition ? Is there any other way to locate Objects faster then to scroll through the navigation pane?
P.S: I am working on Management Studio 2014
DataBase edition is 2005

I tried looking for a solution in Management studio and googled the same but could not find any answer :|

Comment: i  found an option to invoke Object explorer by pressing f7... this opens an 'Object Explorer details Tab' which shows a search box but whatever i type in this box it says just one thing:
"Search failed: failed to retrieve data for this request"

Any suggestions on using this?

Comment: Check out [Red Gate's  Sql Search.](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) It's free. (I do not work for them, I just use this product and think it's good).

Comment: seems a good tool but i this tool also returns no results found. Though the select query with same name of table returns rows!
I have made sure that i have chosen right dataBase name and tables in objects drop down.

is there any practice followed for searching ? like prefixing 'dbo.' or some thing like that ? (i have tried prefixing dbo. and it does not help!)
i think it not allowed to attach screen shots in comments otherwise would have shown u

Also isn't there any other built in way to search?

Comment: From View Menu => Object Explorer Details (F7)

Comment: there is a checkbox for exact match, make sure it's unchecked. also, sql search can't find user defined types for some reason.

Comment: @Sreedhar: F7 (object Explorer details) return: search results failed.
where as Table with same name in select returns results

Comment: @ZoharPeled : yes  , its unchecked

Comment: For more details look here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646011(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: No help Sreedhar :(
I am using 2014 edition..
It says select the database on which u r searching and i tried search after selecting dataBase and Object (tables in the data base drop down) and then i search  but it says Search failed!
Wild cards also did not help

Comment: I just want to know if Data Base makes any impact on this?
i am using a back end data base 2005 edition and one of my colleague told that we can use only select query to view the table and we can not search for the table because of the older version of data base.. but i dont agree with him as i feel that management studio is  responsible for searching..
any thoughts on this?

Comment: The Object Explorer works on my SQL 2019 database, but NOT on my SQL 2008 R2